# CBool function returning integer in Access SQL statement

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, ms-access-2010

I am using C# `ExecuteReader` method to read data from an Access db. I have a string field in the Access table and in my query I am converting it into bool using below code:

```
IIF(IsXYZ = 'True',CBool(1=1),CBool(1=0)) AS IsXYZ
```

Above statement is returning `Int16` value to me in data reader. As per the

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Type-Conversion-Functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202

it's supposed to return `bool`, what am I missing here?

Comment: potentially a driver/provider issue and managed CLI type issue.. but you really haven't provided enough code sample here. Provide which driver/provider you're using (in your connection string) and the code snippet where you ExecuteReader on the derived DbCommand type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what am I missing here?

I don't think you're missing anything. I have recreated your issue using `System.Data.OleDb`, `System.Data.Odbc`, and in Access itself using a `DAO.Recordset`. It seems that `CBool` will return a `Boolean` in a VBA statement, but it will return an `Integer` in an Access SQL statement. :(

Comment: I understand the reason is because Access only partially implements SQL-92 spec (even Access 2019!), and the previous spec, SQL-89 does not define a `boolean` type - the smallest type is `smallint`. OLE-DB has its own `BOOL` which defines `-1` as `true`, and `-1` requires a signed integer representation and the smallest (at the time) is `smallint`. So I guess that explains it - but this isn't authoritative. I'd love to be on Access team at MS and read through the source control history to find out what really happened...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this.

```
CBool(IIf(IsXYZ = 'True',-1,0)) AS IsXYZ
```

One thing worth mentioning is that a Yes/No (True/False) field in Access is translated as a bit field in SQL Server (if converted) and will convert as -1/0 for True/False. BTW 0 is always False and ANY "non-zero" number is considered to be True, so 9087 is also True!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but IMO this should have been posted as a comment because it wasn't tested. I know it wasn't tested because it doesn't solve the problem. ;)

Comment: I tested it in the MS Access immediate window and it worked for me. Maybe it should be tested by Deepak in his C# code?

Comment: Hi, I tried Dave's idea already and it still returns int16, the code block where I am reading the datareader is common between SQL db ad access db, so now I am check the data type of the field retruned(IsXYZ ) datareader from the data reader and then casting it accordingly, SQL db will return a bool whereas access db will return a int16(-1,0). Thanks Gord & Dave for helping.

Comment: One thing worth mentioning is that a Yes/No (True/False) field in Access is translated as a bit field in SQL Server (if converted) and will convert as -1/0 for True/False. BTW 0 is always False and ANY "non-zero" number is considered to be True, so 9087 is also True! I edited my Answer to include this.